# Calling .ToString() on a string to change its format

Tags: c#, string

In order to be able to dynamically change a value in my application I am storing it in the resx file. Of course this is a string.

```
MaximumSpend    -    5000
```

In my code I do `int.Parse(MyApp.MaximumSpend)`. Now I can change the max spend in one place and the application handles it with no futher changes.

In the front end I want to show the value as $5,000.
If this were an int, I would do

```
MyInt.ToString("0#,##0")
```

But it is already a string. I could convert to an int and then call `.ToString()` on it but that seems wasteful.

Is there a much better way of changing 5000 to 5,000 in my front end code? Or is changing to an `int` and back the best way?

UPDATE: Thanks everyone. I've gone ahead and done the int.parse and back to a string.

```
$('#MaximumSpend').text("@int.Parse(MyResources.MyNamespace.MaximumSpend).ToString("##,###")");
```

I'll be using the web.config for this in the future (I've already done that for other items, just not these which started as a purely front-end thing then I decided to use it in the backend).

I have upvoted accordingly

Comment: I would say any other way you can think of probably won't be worth the hassle, so just convert to int and back,

Comment: Store the value in in your app as int, and only convert to a (formatted) string if you need to display the value.

Comment: Basically: no, there's no better way than making it an int. You can't work with a number while it is a string, and parsing and modifying the string would be way worse than just converting it to int and back to string. The ideal would be not having that data as a string in first place, but if it's not possible, then the best way is definitely convert back and forth.

Comment: By the way, resources are perfectly capable of storing integers, no need to store it as a string

Comment: @Jcl I can see in the dropdown in VS2013 you can store images, icons etc and "other". But nothing specifically for a data type of int.

Comment: @VictorySaber I've added how in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **no, there's no better way**

The long answer is:

1. You could parse the string and convert it, but it'd probably be way worse than just converting to `int`, then back to string with formatting.
2. You could just store the value in your resource as an integer directly, instead of as an string. The designer doesn't allow you to directly do it, but you can open the .resx file with a text editor (or in Visual Studio, right click on it, `Open With` and select the `XML Text Editor`), and add your resource on the correct section, like this:

   ```
   <data name="MaximumSpend" xml:space="preserve" type="System.Int32, mscorlib">
      <value>5000</value>
   </data>
   ```

   Afterwards, you can view it on the normal resource editor (you'll see your value in the `Other` section. You can even edit it, just not "add more")

Or:

3. Use a settings file, instead of a resource, which probably makes more sense for this kind of data

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks.

Comment: I'd really go for #3. A "resource" file is not supposed to be a file where you store settings. You store *resources* there (I'd prefer to call them "assets", but "resources" is an ok name too). If you want to store a *setting* (the maximum spenditure in this case), then go for the right tool: use a *settings* file.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that #3 is the best way. I use the web.config for other items like this, but this was one of the first items I added and it has just stuck around.

Comment: @VictorySaber for what it's worth, I'd avoid having "business logic" settings in `web.config`, and leave that to "application settings". You can have your custom settings file for this (in VS, on your project, `Add` -> `New Item` -> `Settings File`, usually with extension `.settings`)

Comment: Yes but isn't the application settings compiled? Some business logic can be in the web.config to allow changes to be made quickly without redeployment of the site. I would not want major functionality changes controlled in this way but MaxSpend would be a candidate.

Comment: Nope, they are not compiled (actually, resources are). With the designer you get a generated file with properties for accessing them, but the value of the settings are stored in xml files (you even get a runtime library for writing and persisting user-scoped settings). Check [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx). Not sure how user-scoped settings work in ASP.NET applications (I guess you'll need to use profiles or something), but it should be easy to experiment with.

Answer (score 3):

Just clone a `en-US` culture (which uses `$` as a [`CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol.aspx)), set it's [`CurrencyDecimalDigits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencydecimaldigits.aspx) to `0` and format your number with [The `"C"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString) and *that* cloned culture as;

```
int i = 5000;
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("C", clone)); // $5,000
```

EDIT: Looks like you have a string `"5000"` in first place, you need to parse it first to `int` with `int.Parse` and *then* can use that integer value to generate specific formatted string.

```
int i = int.Parse("5000");
...
...
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, however the question states that the incoming value is already a string, and he wants to avoid if possible converting it back to int and then call `ToString()` again. Again, I think this is the best way, but is the one the OP wants to avoid

Comment: As per the OP's question: `but it is already a string. I could convert to an int and then call .ToString() on it but that seems wasteful.

Is there a much better way of changing 5000 to 5,000 in my front end code? Or is changing to an int and back the best way?`

Comment: @Jcl Hmm, fair enough. Looks like OP needs to to parse it to `int` first and _then_ generate it's `string` representation with _specific_ format. Updated my answer.

Comment: yeah, what I understand from his question is that that is what he's already doing, and he is trying to find a better way... I personally think there's no better way but you never know :-)

Answer (score 3):

Resx files are not configuration files. They are meant to store static resources, like localized strings, images, and so on.

What you probably want is a Setting, which is two tabs down in the Visual Studio properties. There you can define an application-scoped setting which is typed to be an int, and it will generate a strongly typed accessor. No parsing required*.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyInt.ToString("0#,##0");
```

Here's some more information on the subject: [Using Settings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx).

<sub>* *Technically, it's still parsed, but .NET does it for you.*</sub>

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an actual answer to the question

Comment: He asked for a better way. The better way is to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: I think a better link would be [Using Settings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx)

Comment: @AlexJ even so this kind of skirts around the problem, not actually answering it. For example what if the OP is unable to change where the value is stored

Comment: @sloth: Granted, the use of MyApp.MaximumSpend made me think of VB. However int.Parse is clearly C#.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Then he wouldn't have written "I'm storing it." :)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Then it's the OP's problem for asking for a better way without sufficiently clarifying the limitations the OP is stuck with. It is not a fault in this answer, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing from an `int` and back to a `string` is perhaps the best way. For example:

```
string strIntString = strMaxSpend.Split("-").Trim();
int nValue;
if (!Int32.TryParse(strIntString, out nValue))
{
    //Parse failed
}
```

Note I use `TryParse` instead of a straight `Convert` call incase the conversion fails so we can fail smoothly.

Then just doing the `ToString()` part as mentioned in your question.

Answer (score -2):

Try This :

```
string s = "2342314854";
string s1 = string.Format("{0:C}", Double.Parse(s));
```

Result will be : `$2,342,314,854.00`

this code will work to convert string value into currency.

Comment: No. `N` format specifier does not use _any_ currency stuff,

Comment: We can use C in place of N so it will return result in $ format.

Comment: @VaibhavChaurasiya Depends on `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: @: Soner Gonul : you can do it like thia ----->                                    string s = "2342314854";

NumberFormatInfo nfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK").NumberFormat;
nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)nfi.Clone();

string s1 = string.Format(nfi, "{0:C}", Double.Parse(s));